# Jhipster Oauth2 token 'expires_in' time reduction issue

Tags: token, jhipster, oauth-2.0

I have set jhipster Oauth2 token expire time to '20,000' in **tokenValidityInSeconds** variable of **jhipsterProperties.java** file.

However the expire time of every token I get is not uniform.

Sometime the expire time is only 3,500 seconds or sometimes 18,499 seconds, basically the **expire time of token varies** from 19,999 to 2,500 seconds.

What I wish to know is --

1. Why this happens?
2. if possible, how to keep the token expire time uniform?